# How to Implemented voice based events?

Tags: android, voice, voice-recognition

I want to have a voice based action in my app. For example, when I want to add something into favorites list, then the usual way we follow is to click a button, but here i want to trigger that task by ***voice***, like saying "`Add to Favorites`"..

Is this possible? If so which Libraries should we use for that?

Please provide any relevant hyperlink or suggest github libraries associated with it if any.

There is a sample video at http://vimeo.com/52775114

regards,

Comment: there is no such library )
you can use android speech recognition subsystem. but you wont be able to listen for a user continuously. after recognizing you get a text string, you should analize it by yourself and do something )

Comment: @Leonidos...Thanks but then how it is working plz watch this video... i want to implement this one...http://vimeo.com/52775114

Comment: Then once you get a result tell it to use text to speech, followed by another recognizer intent.

Comment: They did this with their own solution or created IME based on android library. Read this post: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/12/add-voice-typing-to-your-ime.html On android 4+ you will be able to get regodnition results while user is speaking.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html

You can use a recognizerintent which recognises speech returning the data as a string array. It doesn't require any additional libraries etc, it is in fact incredibly easy to code. You start the intent on a button press etc and it will listen and return an interpretation of what was said.

Comment: @AndroidPenguin...Thanks, I thought so in a similar way but it is having some limitations bcas in that case i can check for perticular string or text but user can say anything, I dont want to restrict for perticular text...For example one user could say "add to favorites" another one could say "hey add it to favorites"...

Comment: Check if the string contains the words "add" AND "favourites" or "make" AND "favourites" etc?

Answer (score -1):

Yes,it is possible.Android natively provides feature of Speech to Text API to bulid such voice enabled application.This tutorial would be good start for you..
[Android Speech to Text Coversion](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/)